# How to look for a specific character in an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, search, include, character

I'm trying to look for a specific character in an array but this character is being entered by the user.

I first order the array and then ask the user to enter a specific character and then I should see if that character exists in any of the words that the array has

For some reason, if when checking for the existence of the character, I "hard code" a character, it works, but it doesn't work if I try to look for the character that the user has entered...

```
list = [ 'Mom' , 'Dad' , 'Brother' , 'Sister' ]
puts ("Enter the character you would like to find");
character = gets
for i in 0..(list.length - 1)
if (list[i].include?(#{character}))
puts ("Character #{character} found in the word #{list[i]}");
end
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Investigate the use of [`each`, `select`, `find` and `any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) instead of `for` and using indexed searches through arrays. `For` is not idiomatic Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `gets` adds a `\n` to the end of the string. Use `gets.chomp!` so you can get rid of the last char.

Comment: No problem, just remember to accept the answer if you think it helped so it can help other people.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "chomp" to get rid of the carriage return at the end of the line of the input.  In addition you could condense your code as well.

```
list = [ 'Mom' , 'Dad' , 'Brother' , 'Sister' ]
puts ("Enter the character you would like to find");
character = gets.chomp
list.each do |e|
  puts "Character #{character} found in the word #{e}" if e.include?(character)
end
```